# vuex-persistedstate switch between sessionStorage and localStorage

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I want to switch from sessionStorage to localStorage if the user selects the "Remember Me" check box, also I using vuex-persistedstate

```
export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore({
    state: {
    },
    actions: {
      setLodingMode({ commit }, newMode) {
        commit("SET_LOADING_MODE", newMode);
      },
      resetStates({ commit }) {
        commit("AUTHENTICATION_RESET_STATE");
        commit("login/RESET_STATE");
      },
    },
    modules: { login, authentication },
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  });

  return Store;
});
```

the point is here I want to change like this

```
state: {
      flag: false
        },
plugins: [
      createPersistedState({
        storage: flag ? window.localStorage : window.sessionStorage,
      }),
    ],
```

I want flag change by user "Remember me" checkbox on login, so when the user selects checkbox the flag change to true and all data saved on localStorage

Comment: Hi! This community helps each other debug their attempts at some source code. You maybe want to ask that question in a forum instead. "Please code that for me" is not often seen here to gather attention. If you have source code of your attempts, please share it with us.

Comment: As Peter Krebs said, please make an effort to show something. For your question the best way is to implement yourself a `myOwnStorage` with a flag true/false. If true save in the `localStorage` if false in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: I updated @PeterKrebs

Comment: I did that but doesn't update @Patfreeze

Comment: vuex-persistedstate doesn't supports this kind of switch specifically, as you can see in the docs. You need custom storage that will implement your logic, see https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate#customize-storage . "I did that but doesn't update" - not really, you put a condition in the place that is executed only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the @Estus Flask comment, I used custom storage and I managed the "remember me" option by directly calling localStorage and set a flag in localStorage

```
plugins: [
      createPersistedState({
        paths: ["authentication.userAuthenticationInfo"],
        storage: {
          getItem(key) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("rememberMe") == 1) {
              return localStorage.getItem(key);
            } else {
              return Cookies.get(key);
              //return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
            }
          },
          setItem(key, value) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("rememberMe") == 1) {
              localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } else {
              Cookies.set(key, value);
              //sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
            }
          },
          removeItem(key) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("rememberMe") == 1) {
              localStorage.removeItem(key);
            } else {
              Cookies.remove(key);
              //sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
```

and I clear localStorage in every logout or 401 response